# Unexpected auto-formatting of XML layout in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-xml, android-studio-3.0

I am using AS since 4 years. After last update I observed unexpected auto-formatting of XML layout (while typing and with `Code` -> `Reformat Code` too).

Here is an example:

1. When I started typing relative layout, it expanded start tag, width property, height property and closing tag in the same line.
2. Properties starts after indentation.
3. No space between views after reformat.

**Question**

- Is this a *feature* in new AS? then how can I revert it back?
- Did I change some setting? What setting should I modify to revert back? (I tried to find on google but could not find anything)

[image]

I am using 
Android Studio 3.2.1
Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on October 8, 2018

Comment: Did you close the `DrawerLayout`? close everything which started then try the same thing again.

Comment: Yes, It is hidden under tip-box.

Comment: Please give some constructive comments for your downvotes. Silent downvotes are not helping the community.

Comment: This blog post explains when the problem started occurring (faulty upgrade code from Google in Android Studio 3.5) and how to fix it: https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/08/21/android-studio-3p5-xml-reformatting-problems.html

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### Update

> if you facing same issue with `Android Studio 3.5` please check below article

[Android Studio 3.5 Upgrade XML Reformatting Problems](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/08/21/android-studio-3p5-xml-reformatting-problems.html)

Open `File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > XML`

Now in layout file make sure you have selected wrap attributes as **Wrap always**

Like below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: For me it was not using custom style. I enabled it and also checked the option "Insert line break before attribute" checked. It worked.

Comment: Same issue with me. By default it wasn't using custom style. Thanks to @NileshRathod for this answer!

Comment: For me, changing that Scheme from Project to Default would do the trick

Answer (score 32):

for me it's working

```
Open Settings > Editor > Code Style > XML > Arrangements
Click Set from... text
Select Predefined Styles > Android
Click Apply button
```

[image: open preferences]

[image: go to XML code style]

[image: set predefined Android style]

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/08/21/android-studio-3p5-xml-reformatting-problems.html