# Why not reformat XML codes in Kotlin on Android

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

I want develop android application with **Kotlin** language in **Android studio 3.2.1**.
When i develop app with **java**, after create `XML` when use **Ctrl + Alt + L** (or **Shift + Ctrl + Alt + L**) reformat `XML` codes .

But when develop app with **kotlin**, after create `XML` when use **Ctrl + Alt + L** not reformat `XML` codes. show me bad style of codes!!!

**My xml codes :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                           android:orientation="vertical">
            <Button
                    android:text="File page"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/btnFile"
                    android:background="@color/blue_grey_800"
                    android:textColor="@color/amber_50"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnSend"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btnSend"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnSend" android:typeface="sans"
                    android:textSize="18sp"/>
            <Button
                    android:text="AsyncTask with Quiz app"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/btnAsync"
                    android:background="@color/blue_grey_400"
                    android:textColor="@color/amber_50"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btnSend"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnSend" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                    android:typeface="sans" android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnBasicFragment"/>
            <Button
                    android:text="Basic Fragment"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/btnBasicFragment"
                    android:background="@color/blue_grey_500"
                    android:textColor="@color/amber_50"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btnSend"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnSend" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    android:typeface="sans" android:textSize="18sp" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnBasicRetrofit"/>
            <Button
                    android:text="Retrofit and RxJava"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/btnBasicRetrofit"
                    android:background="@color/blue_grey_600"
                    android:textColor="@color/amber_50"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btnSend"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnSend" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnBasicRecycler"
                    android:typeface="sans" android:textSize="18sp"/>
            <Button
                    android:text="Divar simple"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/btnDivar"
                    android:background="@color/blue_grey_200"
                    android:textColor="@color/amber_50"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btnSend"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnSend" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    android:typeface="sans" android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnCustomView"/>
            <Button
                    android:text="Custom View"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/btnCustomView"
                    android:background="@color/blue_grey_300"
                    android:textColor="@color/amber_50"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btnSend"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnSend" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    android:typeface="sans" android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnAsync"/>
            <Button
                    android:text="Send page"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/btnSend" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:background="@color/blue_grey_900"
                    android:textColor="@color/amber_50" android:textAllCaps="false" android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:typeface="sans"/>
            <Button
                    android:text="Basic RecyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/btnBasicRecycler"
                    android:background="@color/blue_grey_700"
                    android:textColor="@color/amber_50"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btnSend"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnSend" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnFile"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:typeface="sans"/>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How can i reformat `XML` codes when use **Kotlin**?!

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52853796/7666442

Comment: @NileshRathod, i check this link . my setting is such as accept image! this problem show me just kotlin language! :(

Comment: @Jakewarton : It's not related to kotlin project I think. I also face same issue sometimes even though I have same setting as NileshRathod mention. Just try remove that setting and apply again. I know this is weird but I solved like that.